# Mostrar todas las celdas de una tabla

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Necesito mostrar todas las celdas de mi tabla, sin importar que estén vacías.
Esta tabla muestra datos relacionados pero cuando no hay ninguna coincidencia se queda así vacía. ¿Cómo podré hacer para que se llenen todos los campos de la tabla así no haya relación entre ellos?

Como pueden ver en la imagen, hay unos campos vacíos que no se están pintando, a eso me refiero, necesito mostrar las líneas así esté vacío. Para que la tabla se vea pareja.

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Intente agregar una condición, pero no me funciono.
Esta es la función que pinta la tabla:

```
import React from "react";
import "../assets/styles/Table.css";

const Table = ({ table, id }) => {
  return (
    <div className="table-wrapper">
      <table className="containerTable" id={id}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {table.columnas.map((columns, i) =>
              columns === "" ? <td key={i}></td> : <td key={i}>{columns}</td>
            )}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {table.data.map((rows, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              {[...rows].map((values, i) =>
                values === "" ? <td key={i}></td> : <td key={i}>{values}</td>
              )}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Y estos son los estilos que tiene:

```
.containerTable {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.table-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.table-wrapper table thead th,
.table-wrapper table tbody td {
  border: 0.1px solid #0e3a73;
  empty-cells: show;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Esto muestra table

```
{"filas":[null,"42966414","70744361","08453100","10197075","80228541","41667376","07461671","40137406","44202123","01870087","46518452","20532057","15358913","41276688","32028784","002335320","47397154","40916178","25755976","42937450","42099254","41740528","00251971","46222913","43228412","40887352"],"columnas":[null,"LAVA","LAVAX","M&K","ARO","POR ASIGNAR","MISAY"],"data":[[null,72284.69756999997,2185554.4487799983,20904.99675,135525.19660000002,500],["42966414",2197.19833,483.92597],["70744361",null,null,null,null,390.50847],["08453100",null,null,22.88434,null,25.42372],["10197075",0,null,null,null,0,0],["80228541",null,null,null,33.4661],["41667376",16.45762,30.10168,null,234.26269999999997],["07461671",3898.53365,null,null,2615.87101],["40137406",null,null,null,33.4661,0],["44202123",null,0,null,null,338.98305],["01870087",0],["46518452",0],["20532057",0],["15358913",null,0],["41276688",null,0],["32028784",18.94915],["002335320",null,null,null,null,0],["47397154",null,null,null,null,0],["40916178",null,null,null,null,0],["25755976",null,null,null,null,0],["42937450",null,null,null,null,0],["42099254",null,null,null,null,0],["41740528",null,null,null,null,169.49153],["00251971",null,451.5254],["46222913",null,null,null,null,0],["43228412",null,null,null,null,0],["40887352",null,null,null,null,0]]}
```

Comment: Si tu problema es de CSS debes colocar un ejemplo reproducible. td{ background-color: red;}

Comment: @Yussef acabo de editar la pregunta porqueme di cuenta que el problema no es de css, sino de la funcion que relaciona los datos para pintar la tabla.

Comment: Al decir pintar parece que lo que quieres es ponerle color, realmente buscas dibujar la tabla ¿correcto? Pero ls celdas vacía se ven con sus bordes ¿te refieres a las celdas de la tercera columna filas 3,4,5?

Comment: Segun me parece (no se reactjs, que conste) el problema lo tienes aquí: `{[...rows].map((values, i) => (`  donde solo mapeas las columnas con valores, y por lo tanto no creas los `<td></td>` vacios.  Quizás deberías cambiar eso por algun tipo de `for( i=0; i>table.columnas.length; i++)` que te asegurara que vas a imprimirlas todas, y dentro ir poniendo los `values` en las columnas que deban llevarlo y dejando vacias, pero con el `<td></td>`, las que no les corresponda ningún valor.

Comment: @masterguru gracias, efectivamente eso es lo que me esta pasando. Necesito mapear toda la tabla pero en reactjs no sabia como crear ese for, si alguien me podria orientar, lo agradezco.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de los datos que te llegan en table

Comment: @Pipe edite la pregunta y agregue una imagen donde se muestran los datos que trae table...

Comment: mejor utiliza `console.log(JSON.stringify(table))` y agrega eso como texto a la pregunta... no como imagen

Comment: @Pipe ya corregi la pregunta como indicaste

Comment: Yo personalmente no puedo ver la supuesta imagen que insertaste en la pregunta para mostrar como se veia la tabla, pero basado en el json que mandas supongo que el problema lo tienes en las ultimas columnas, cuando estas no tienen valor... es así? O podrías intentar [edit] tu pregunta para agregar correctamente la imagen y poder visualizarlo mejor?

Comment: Y si es así, el problema está en como generas los datos, si vuelves a la pregunta anterior te darás cuenta que en mi solución todas las filas tienen la misma cantidad de datos, en tu ejemplo aqui no, entonces no aplicaste la solución completa que ya te había dado. Te falto la primera línea dentro del for `fila.length = datosTabla.columnas.length;`

Comment: @Pipe si efectivamente es asi, no agregue esa linea de codigo debido a que no me funciona con todas las  combinaciones, la acabo de agregar y me acaba de arrojar este error cuando intento crear un tabla --->  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'length')

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140509/discussion-between-pipe-and-naidamag).